# DecimalFormat truncating preceding zero from double value

Tags: java

```
    double a = 3.00;
    DecimalFormat newForamt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            a = Double.valueOf(newForamt.format(a));
    System.out.println(a);
```

This is giving me 3.0 though i want to maintain the succeeding zeros.
Can anyone please suggest how can i do that.
I went through lot of solutions on net but nothing seems to work for me?

Comment: You do realize you are printing `a` and not a String containing a formatted number, right?

Comment: Why are you assigning to double again?Formatting is for printing purpose than calculation purpose. System.out.println(newFormat.format(a));

Comment: yeah but i need to return a number with the succeeding zeros

Comment: 1) How does it make difference in calculation 2) If you want to return formatted one return String which is result of newFormat.format(a)

Comment: It doesnt makes a difference in calculation but as a final result i have to return the same value with exact same precision as i am getting from the DB.

Comment: What type is it in the database exactly?

Comment: its a decimal value....with precision upto two decimal digits and having numbers like 122.00

Answer (score 1):

This is a printing issue, you need to use the `DecimalFormat`:

```
System.out.println(newForamt.format(a));
```

Comment: I need to return a double value not just print it...So if i return newForamt.format(a) will it return me a string or a double value?
I guess it will return me a string and as soon as i will convert this string to double all the succeeding zeros will be truncated

Comment: The actual value of the double does not care how you print it. A double value does not contain any trailing zero, it is just the representation of the value.

Comment: problem is not the representation of the value instead it is the type of value....It needs to be double and not string...I may not have been very clear but instead of printing the value as in prototype mentioned above i actually have to return a double value.

Answer (score 0):

following code will return as it is value which u getting from database

```
double a = 3.00;        
DecimalFormat newForamt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(newForamt.format(a)); 
System.out.println(bd1);//prints 3.00
```